# Как кратко инициализировать объекты

Tags: c#, объекты

```
Cell cellCenter = new Cell(x, y);
Cell cellCenterUp = new Cell(x, y - 1);
Cell cellCenterDown = new Cell(x, y + 1);

Cell cellCenterLeft = new Cell(x - 1, y);
Cell cellUpLeft = new Cell(x - 1, y - 1);
Cell cellDownLeft = new Cell(x - 1, y + 1);

Cell cellCenterRight = new Cell(x + 1, y);
Cell cellUpRight = new Cell(x + 1, y - 1);
Cell cellDownRight = new Cell(x + 1, y + 1);

List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>()
{ 
    cellCenter,
    cellCenterDown,
    cellCenterLeft,
    cellCenterRight,
    cellCenterUp,
    cellDownLeft,
    cellUpLeft,
    cellUpRight,
    cellDownRight
};
```

Как то можно саму инициализацию объектов переписать в меньшое количество строк?

Comment: Ну если переменные ни для чего больше не нужны, то можно так сократить `List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>() { new Cell(x, y), new Cell(x, y - 1) /*и так все остальные*/ };`

Answer (score 0):

Например, так

```
List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();

int x=10;
int y=15;

for(int i=-1; i<=1; i++)
for(int j=-1; j<=1; j++)
    cells.Add(new Cell(x+i, y+j));
```